# Passing data between angular controllers using service

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having trouble passing data between controllers using a service. What i want to happen is when send data is clicked the data inputted into the text field should be populated in the Results controller. However nothing shows

Home.html:

```
   <html>
<body>
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="StockUpdateCtrl">

    <div class="list">         
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to Refresh" on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
    <div>{{text}}</div>
    <input type='text' ng-model='text' />

     <button type='button' ng-click='send()'>Send Data</button>
     <div ng-controller='ResultsController'>
  <div>
    <h4>Ctrl2</h4>
    <div>{{text}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
    </body>
    </html>
```

HomeController.js:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])


        .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
                // for form inputs)
                if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                }
                if (window.StatusBar) {
                    StatusBar.styleDefault();
                }
            });
        })


/*
 * Data Service 
 * Service used to pass data between controllers
 */
app.factory('dataShare', function(){
   var service = {};
  service.data = false;
  service.sendData = function(data){
      this.data = data;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');
  };
  service.getData = function(){
    return this.data;
  };
  return service;
});

/* 
 * Stock Update Controller
 * Gets user input and then performs calculations to prepare to be displayed
 * 
 */
app.controller("StockUpdateCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataShare) {


    $scope.text = 'Hey';
         $scope.send = function(){
           dataShare.sendData($scope.text);
         };



});
```

ResultsController.js:

```
 * Resultse Controller
 * Displays the results
 * 
 */
app.controller("ResultsController",function ($scope, dataShare) {

    $scope.text = '';
                $scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
                            var text =  dataShare.getData();    
              $scope.text = text;
        });
});
```

Comment: Is the event being caught in ResultsController?

Comment: @matmo yes when i hit calcualte i put a break in results and it goes to there.  It must be how i am switching views that is resetting the data, because things work fine on the same page but however when i need the data to load on another view it seems to call the app.factory again and resets the data. Here is the issue when the app is FIRST loaded and the calculate button is hit.. when it switches to the results view the data does not appear.. however any subsequent clicks of calculate the result page properly shows the persisted data

Here is my JS code that handles the views

Answer (score 0):

Haha figured it out. Yes it turned out it was the way i was calling the results page... I had to remove form tag

```
<form action="index.html#/results" ng-controller="StockUpdateCtrl">
```

and change my button to call the results page as such

```
<button type="submit" ui-sref="results"  ng-click="calculate()" class="button button-block button-balanced">
```